# ASP.NET MVC - How to transfer the selected item from DropDownListFor to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I'm making a `DropDownListFor` and pulling its items with the model.

But I cannot transfer the selected item from `DropDownListFor` to the controller.

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StudentTable", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <p>Class:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="SelectedId">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <option value="@item.ClassId">@item.Class.ClassName</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Ara">
    </p>
}
```

Controller:

```cs
StudentDatabaseContext db = new StudentDatabaseContext();
public ActionResult Index(string SelectedId)
{
    var studentList = db.StudentTables.Include(x => x.Class).ToList();
    var degerler = from d in db.StudentTables select d;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedId))
    {
        degerler = degerler.Where(m => m.ClassId.ToString().Contains(SelectedId));
    }
    return View(degerler.ToList());
}
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the `name` attribute to the `select` element, so the value will be passed as `SelectedId` to the controller.

```
<select class="form-control" id="SelectedId" name="SelectedId">
    ...
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your valuable response and effort. The code worked but there is a small bug. For example, when I search for class `A`, if there are 2 students in class `A`, there are 2 `A`'s in `DropDownListFor`. Or if I searched for class `B` and there are 6 students belonging to class `B`, there are 6 `B`s in `DropDownListFor`. Why could this be?

Comment: Hmmm, because you eager load the Student for the related Class record. Instead, you should directly query the Class record for the class option. Steps: 1. Query `Class` record and store to `ViewBag`. 2. Generate the option from ViewBag in View.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do what you said because I can't use more than one `Model` in a `View`.

Comment: Yes, only 1 ViewModel in View. Hence you need to store the `Class` record in `ViewBag` or `ViewData`.

Comment: Do I pull from `ViewBag` ? Do I pull from `ViewBag`? How can I shoot? Sorry if I'm tiring you. I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: It should be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/yongshun950824/375e20aff039b2d611f499c31f3eb3ff)

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I got an error: https://imgur.com/a/iJ9K3sJ. Error in View.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247119/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-emir-bolat).